# Mysql 8.0 problem Quick query results, but slow insertion

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I queried from a 20GB data table A, and the query result was 40,000 rows of data. My query was "select distinct custid from A where '2022-01-01' is between col1 and col2." Since col1 and col2 were indexed, I could obtain all 40,000 rows of data in just 3 seconds. However, when I wanted to insert this result into table B, the query became "insert into table B select distinct custid from A where '2022-01-01' is between col1 and col2," and it took 5 minutes. What is the reason for this?

5 minutes is the time required for a full table scan once.

The 'type' in the 'EXPLAIN' result for the SELECT statement changed from 'range' to 'ALL' when I added the 'insert' operation.

Comment: *What is the reason for this?* Try to remove all indices from this temptable and test...

Comment: 20G I guess is 20 gigbyte but whats 4W? Also please publish the queries as text together with the table definitions.

Comment: i create new table with only one column,there is no index,it still took me 5 mins . sorry, it is 40k, not 4W.

Comment: *"after adding 'INSERT TABLE B' before it,"* - i do wonder how the query looked like, is it a procedure? do you have triggers? or the `insert` become slower after adding indexes? how was disk usage, is it maxed out?

Comment: my query is 'insert into table B select distinct custid from A where '2022-01-01' between col1 and col2'. without 'insert into table B', it is fast. but the selection result had only 40k data,so i think it may take a few more seconds instead of 5 mins.

Comment: Test `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE b SELECT DISTINCT custid FROM a WHERE '2022-01-01' BETWEEN col1 AND col2;`. Of course drop existing table before executing.

Comment: I ran the command using an temporary table, and it still took 5 minutes. 5 minutes is the time it takes for a full table scan once. I believe the core issue is that after adding 'insert into,' it no longer utilizes the index.

Comment: Please post TEXT results from A) EXPLAIN INSERT into ......... and B) SHOW CREATE TABLE A; for analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MySQL optimizer believes that using an index during insertion may decrease efficiency, and thus, it defaults to a full table scan. However, when I use FORCE INDEX, the insertion speed significantly improves, and it no longer performs a full table scan. It is advisable to forcefully use an index at appropriate times instead of letting the optimizer decide the query plan.